# Turning off screen

Tags: monitors

In Arch Linux, is it possible to turn off the screen without going through xorg (with `xset dpms force off`)?  I have seen that `sudo vbetool dpms off` is supposed to work, but it does not on my system (Macbook Air).

Comment: I have `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` in my old laptop. Echoing some value helps me to change brightness or turn off it (`echo 0`). Maybe this info helps you.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, thanks.  this would require storing the old value and restoring when lid opens. .......... or copying the file to `/tmp` and back.

Comment: I don't remember behaviour when lid opens because I sold my old laptop about 2 years ago. But I remember that value of brightness resets to default after system reboot.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, according to powertop, this method doesn't save any power.

Comment: agreed. I've always work from AC (battery was broken) and this scenario was enough for me.